Optimizing retrieving up to X rows in secondary table per parent row in a primary table
I'm looking to find the best general approach to retrieving up to a given number of records in a secondary table for each record previously retrieved in a primary table.
Technical Situation
For the sake of argument, consider the following use case of two tables, a user table and a user_activity table that tracks their activity on a website:
User Table (just what's relevant for this question):



userid
username




1
john.smith@mail.com


2
jane.doe@mail.com



Activity table:



activityid
userid
createdon
other fields describing activity, length ~1kB




1
1
2024-04-18 10:00:00
lengthy description 1


2
1
2024-04-18 10:01:00
lengthy description 2



The user table is rather small, say 10k lines. The user_activity table on the other hand is much larger, say on average 1000 user_activity for each user, 10 millions in total.
A typical way of fetching the last up to 100 activities, as suggested by Postgres documentation on Window functions is this:
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY createdon DESC) AS activity_rank
     FROM user_activity
  ) AS subselect
WHERE activity_rank <= 100;

However, I am worried that with this approach, the full dataset is loaded into memory by the subselect, including the fields describing the activity, which I do want in the final result of my query. That would result in loading the full 10 million rows for about 10GB of total volume.
Would Postgres indeed load the entire dataset into memory to perform that query?
If it does, would it be a better approach to perform the request as follows:
SELECT *
FROM user_activity
INNER JOIN (SELECT activityid,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY createdon DESC) AS activity_rank
     FROM user_activity
  ) AS subselect ON user_activity.activityid = subselect.activityid
WHERE activity_rank <= 100;

In this case, my understanding is that the inner subselect would still load 10 million rows, but only two integers (activityid and rank), so ~20B per row instead of ~1kB, and 20MB in total instead of 10GB, and then the outer subselect would load the data for just 1 million rows (100 per user * 10k users).
Alternatively, can you think of a better way to achieve that?
Extra context
I'm developing a library that processes incoming queries that follow a standard (OData 4.01, to be specific), and transforms them into DB queries. One of the features in that standard/protocol is that you can expand (understand "join", in DB jargon) to retrieve related entities within the same request. The OData query that would correspond to the use case I'm presenting here would look something like that:
GET /users?$expand=user_activities($orderby=createdon desc;$top=100)
In natural language, it reads as "Retrieve all users, and for each of them, their latest activities, up to 100"
That lib is supposed to be generic and work on different data structures. I understand that there will be better optimizations to make to answer this or that specific use case, but given these restrictions, I'm looking for the best generic approach to this matter, so that users of the library can delay implementing such optimizations for as long as possible when their dataset size increases.

The way you can find out what columns are actually returned by which step of the execution is to use EXPLAIN (VERBOSE) (look at the Output for each node).
In your case, you will probably see that all columns of all rows are fetched and then sorted, so your worry is founded. However, I'd assume that the additional self-join in your improved query is even more expensive. Use EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) to see if that is actually the case.
With your data, it might be more efficient to first find all different userid and then find the last 100 rows for each one:
WITH RECURSIVE users AS (
   SELECT min(userid) AS uid FROM user_activity
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT min(userid) FROM user_activity
           WHERE user_activity.userid > users.uid)
   FROM users WHERE users.uid IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT s.*
FROM users
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM user_activity
                       WHERE user_activity.userid = users.uid
                       ORDER BY user_activity.createdon DESC
                       LIMIT 100) AS s;

This would need an index on (userid, createdon).
